# boost multi_index_container broken indexes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a multi_index container. Chan::Ptr is a shared_pointer to the object.
The container has two indexes with object functions.

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    Chan::Ptr,
        indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<const_mem_fun<Chan,string,&Chan::Channel> >,         
        ordered_non_unique<const_mem_fun<Chan,string,&Chan::KulsoSzam> > >
    > ChanPtrLista;
```

Until I push_back objects only into the container, all searching in container is successful.

When I modify the values in the objects (example: Chan::Channel changes) index will be broken. Listing the container with an index, give back a wrong order. However the find functions isn't work anymore.

How can I re-index the container? ("rearragne" method do nothing with indexes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When making changes to an item inside a Boost multi index, you should use the [`modify`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#modify) method exposed by the index object. The `modify` method has the following signature:

```
bool modify(iterator position, Modifier mod);
```

Where:

- `position` is an iterator pointing to the item to update
- `mod` is a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) that accepts a single parameter (the object you want to change).

It returns `true` if the modification occurred successfully, or `false` if it failed.

When the modify function is run, the functor updates the item you want to change, and then the indexes are all updated.

Example:

```
class ChangeChannel
{
public:
  ChangeSomething(const std::string& newValue):m_newValue(newValue)
  {
  }

  void operator()(Chan &chan)
  {
    chan.Channel = m_newValue;
  }

private:
  std::string m_newValue;
};


typedef ChanPtrLista::index<0>::type ChannelIndex;
ChannelIndex& channelIndex = multiIndex.get<0>();

ChannelIndex::iterator it = channelIndex.find("Old Channel Value");

// Set the new channel value!
channelIndex.modify(it, ChangeChannel("New Channel Value"));
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating).

Comment: Thx... I will try in minutes :):):)

Comment: It's works! With some modifications. Example: "Chan::Ptr" instead of "Chan &chan"...
Thank you again!!! :):):):)